# How to create a train and test set based on date criteria

Tags: r, split, training-data

[Data Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yakeI.png)

Hello I need to Use WkBeg < “2015-01-01” for training data, and
WkBeg >= “2015-01-01” for test data. Here is my code but I am getting error messages. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
salesdata2 <- pivot_longer(salesdata2, 3:5, names_to = "Product", values_to = "Sales")
View(salesdata2)

#create test and train sets
salesdata2$WkBeg <- as.Date(salesdata2$WkBeg, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
View(salesdata2)
N = as.Date("2015-01-01") #where you want to split
training = salesdata2[WkBeg<N]
test = salesdata2[WkBeg>=N]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are missing a comma when you are trying to split the data. Since salesdata2 is a dataframe, the brackets need to have a a common in them since a data frame has two dimensions (rows and columns). Vectors like N only have one dimension so have in a comma in the brackets wouldn't work. See below and you should stop getting errors.

`training = salesdata2[WkBeg<N,] test = salesdata2[WkBeg>=N,]`